Is there a way to use SwiftUI Link within a .sheet modifier?
Like the title says... I'm trying to use the new Link syntax in a sheet modifier but I'm running in to all kinds of problems. This is a Sean Allen tutorial that I am just playing with and trying to add some of the new swift features to.
What is currently working is:
@State private var isShowingSafariView = false

 Button {
                isShowingWebView = true
            } label: {
                    AFButton(title: "Learn More")
            }

            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isShowingSafariView, content: {
                SafariView(url: URL(string: framework.urlString) ?? URL(string: "www.apple.com")!)
            })

Of course SafariView is handling the URL/View, but I was trying to simplify this and not use it at all.

I've made this work, but it requires a complete overhaul of how I've built the button. I'm pretty new and I was just trying to figure out if there was just something super simple that I've missed.
My desired result is something like this:
@State private var isShowingSafariView = false

 Button {
                isShowingSafariView = true
            } label: {
                    AFButton(title: "Learn More")
            }

            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isShowingSafariView, content: {
                Link(URL(string: framework.urlString)!)
            })


What is your desired result? What do you want to see in the fullScreenCover? And why don't you want to use SafariView? How does it "requires a complete overhaul of how I've built the button"?

This may be a more clear approach: AFButton(title: "Learn More") { showSafari() } or SafariButton(title: "Learn More", url: myURL)

@Sweeper - The attached gif is the desired result and is what I have built and working so far.

I'm just playing around with this and trying to use Link to simplify things. Ultimately I would like to use Link instead of SafariView.

Ah, after some more reading I found out what I was trying to do.
I was trying to use Link and get the same functionality as SafariServices.. without using SafariServices.

A Link can’t open a webpage in a ful screen cover. It will bring the user to their default browser. What’s so complicated about SafariView? What is there to “simplify”? This doesn’t make sense.

Nothing, I'm just experimenting.  You know, having fun with code and learning.
SafariView is easy. Link is easier but limiting. openURL is even easier, but without modifiers it seems the customization is limited.
